# install dependencies on raspberry pi

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte, raspberrypi, dependencies, image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I installed ros fuerte in my raspberry pi in which there is raspbian wheezy and all work fine.
Now i must use the raspberry to receive a stream video from a webcam and publish the images, but when i create the package, doesn't find the dependecies image_transport opencv and cv_bridge.
How can install its without reinstall ros?
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56347/install-dependencies-on-raspberry-pi/) by [mrpiccolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4072/mrpiccolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They may not be available for the Raspberry Pi it's an experimental platform at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0